# Rails 5.1.4 after upgrade DuplicateMigrationNameError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-migrations, ruby-on-rails-5.1, rails-upgrade

I recently updated a Rails 4.2 app to 5.1.4. After upgrading, whenever I try to run rake db:migrate, I get a `DuplicateMigrationNameError`. The first few times, the error pointed to a file so I just changed the name of the migration class and the file name. But after 4 such changes, the rake task threw the error for the file I just changed, with the new file name/class name. If I changed it back, it still threw the same error. If I changed it to something totally new the same thing happened; it picked up the new filename and threw a `DuplicateMigrationNameError`. I do not have a duplicate file, there are no cached files that I can find. I am running the rails app in a vagrant vm running ubuntu 16.04. The migrations all ran fine on rails 4.2.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue. I don't have any duplicated migration class names in my project folder.

Comment: @stephen - Did you find the solution? I'm facing the same issue when I update rails from 3 to 5. Same migrations are working fine in rails 3.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen when the class name of the migration is duplicated. Open the migrations and see if the class names are identical.

Comment: Same issue. Don't have any duplicated class names.